# MS access sum(iif()) assistance

Tags: ms-access, sum, iif

I'm building a report in MS Access - I came across something that I'm having a difficult time with. Basically the report is comprised of a bunch of info, but I only care about two items. I have 2 columns - 1stAppt, and 2ndAppt. The user enters a date range - say 1/1/2016 - 4/1/2016 for the report. What I'm trying to do is this....if the 1stAppt falls within the date range, then it is a '1', same with 2ndAppt - this I do in my query. In some cases the 1stAppt might not have been within the date range, but 2ndAppt was - here I want to make sure that I have a '1' in 1stAppt column where 2ndAppt = 1. And heres where I have my problem - because I can't figure out the statement that would do it. Here's what I tried with...

```
=sum(iif((2ndappt=1) and (1stAppt=0), sum(1stAppt=1), sum(1stAppt))
```

So in a case where 2ndAppt=1 and 1stAppt=0, I'm trying to make that row in 1stAppt = 1 - then I'm trying to take the total of all 1stAppt (this includes row where 1stAppt was previously 0 and 2ndAppt was a 1). I don't know if I'm making sense here.

summary: If 2ndAppt = 1 and 1stAppt=0 then make 1stAppt=1 and take sum of all 1stAppt (the ones that were 1's before, and new 1's that I've just changed to 1). If 1stAppt=1 and 2ndAppt=0, then I don't care about it. I need to make sure that 1stAppt is taken into account if it falls out of the date range, as long as 2ndAppt falls within the date range.

Comment: I don't understand at all.  I don't see any VBA code.  Is there some?  If not, I suggest you remove the tag.

Comment: 2 colums - 1stAppt and 2ndAppt - if either one falls within the Date Range then its =1. if date range is 4/1/2016-4/20/16  and 1stAppt date is 4/2/2016 then I will see a 1 under 1stAppt. Same thing with 2ndAppt. In some cases 1stAppt might not be in the date range - but 2ndAppt is. In this case 2ndAppt=1 and 1stAppt=0. I'm trying to make sure that for each row of data where 2ndAppt=1 - 1stAppt is also 1. Then I need to take a sum of all data in 1stAppt (all the records that are in the date range, and the ones that were not but were converted to 1 because of 2ndAppt being 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a separate IIF() statement for each Appt field. Appt1 can be solved by nesting:

```
Appt1Test: IIF(Appt1 Between [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateStart] And [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateEnd], 1, 
           IIF(IIF(Appt2 Between [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateStart] And [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateEnd], 1, 0)=1,1,0))
Appt2Test: IIF(Appt2 Between [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateStart] 
           And [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateEnd], 1, 0)
```

Then in your WHERE clause of the query used as the report control source:

```
WHERE Appt1Test = 1 AND Appt2Test = 1
```

If you put the IIF statement in the same query as the control source, your WHERE statement needs to include the Test expression:

```
WHERE IIF(Appt1 Between [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateStart] And [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateEnd], 1, 
      IIF(IIF(Appt2 Between [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateStart] And [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateEnd], 1, 0)=1,1,0))=1
AND IIF(Appt2 Between [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateStart] 
    And [Forms]![frmMyForm]![DateEnd],1,0)=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!